# Dropdown element not interactable Using python

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, hidden

(Edit)
So lemme be clear as I was vague before (apologies). I am writing this test case which selects a drop-down, updates it by pressing the update button, and the changes are responsible for another option to start running and vice versa. Now when I select an option from a Select element. Visually when I run the script it gets selected and it looks for the changes on another page. but due to some issues, the changes are not reflected and the test case fails. When I checked it manually, the dropdown option that I selected is not updated. When I do it manually, it updates and everything is working fine. i used explicit waits, java script, and almost everything i know but it won't budge.

Here is my HTML if it makes sense:

```html
<div class="d-flex align-items-center">
  <div class="MuiFormControl-root">
    <div class="MuiInputBase-root jss6907 MuiInputBase-formControl" style="min-width: 200px;">
      <select class="MuiNativeSelect-root MuiNativeSelect-select MuiInputBase-input jss6908" aria-invalid="false">
        <option value="" disabled="">Select Compressor 1 Manual State</option>
        <option value="0.0">OFF</option>
        <option value="1.0">ON</option>
      </select>
      <svg class="MuiSvgIcon-root MuiNativeSelect-icon" focusable="false" viewBox="0 0 24 24" aria-hidden="true">
        <path d="M7 10l5 5 5-5z">
        </path>
      </svg>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So currently im using this:

```
dropdown = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="panel1a-content"]/div/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]/div/div/div/select')
                    selectVal = Select(dropdown)
                    selectVal.select_by_value("1.0")
```

This is during the visual stuff. I tried to implement a check using is.displayed() and it showed that the element is not displayed. It could be the reason, but I'm not sure. I also tested through a refresh and then checked the before and after values and it gave me this:

After updating, dropdown value is:  1.0
After Refreshing the driver.
After Refreshing, dropdown value is:  0.0

Could there be some way I can handle this situation?

Comment: Can you add the `HTML` for that element ?

Comment: @moken Apologies, i have updated the question now!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `JavaScript` to interact with the element directly, this will bypass the visibility of element

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

dropdown = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="panel1a-content"]/div/div[1]/div/table/tbody/tr[7]/td[2]/div/div/div/select')

driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView();", dropdown)

selectVal = Select(dropdown)

selectVal.select_by_value("1.0")
```

Comment: Hey @Akzy, Thanks for the response, but unfortunately it didn't work as well. Now i don't understand what the problem is, but it didn't work. i tried waits, Select, manually using the xpaths, selectorsHub but all of them options didn't worked

Comment: What `error` are you getting ?

Comment: i'm not getting any error, its doing the same thing as before. so nothing changed.

Comment: Hey there. I have updated my question if ut makes sense. any other options I could try? I have tried .wait(), I have tried action chains, I have tried js executers but still I'm stuck on the same point.